# Copy formula and paste it externally

Tags: front-end

I don't manage to copy a cell (or part of it) from a notebook and paste it somewhere else (example, in the internet search bar). I tried to change the style of the cell but the result didn't change.

Do I have to change something in my settings/preference of Mathematica?

N.B. I work on a Linux Ubuntu OS.

Comment: Edit -> Copy As -> Plain Text?

Comment: @Melago. It doesn't solve. I discovered that my issue is not featured in all notebooks. In some of them the standard cut and paste (or equivalently the MelaGo's trick) works, while in others doesn't.

Comment: Before copy and paste convert the cell to [`Raw InputForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/menuitem/RawInputForm.html)

Answer (score 0):

This

[image]

is an equation in one of my Mma files. Below you see the same formula copy-pasted into Word (Office 365).

[image]

The only trick I used was to select the image after pasting, right-click and to choose "Professional" from the drop-down menu. If it is OK for you, try this.

Have fun!

Comment: Thanks. However I don't want to copy the image of cell in its enriched fashon. I want to copy the text in raw cell. If in the cell I have   f[x_]:=2^x  ,  what I want is simply to be able to copy this string as it is in, say, the internet search bar.

Comment: Maybe converting to `TeXForm` and do a post-processing?